# queryparm support in spring for restful web services

Tags: java, spring, rest, query-string

How can I get `queryparam` support of restful web service by spring in true restful manner...

for example  i have url like following

> localhost:8080/myapp/booksearch/title/{title}/author/{author}?sortby=relevance&year=2013

title and author I can get by `@PathVariable` .....

where i want sortby and year optional..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the [`@RequestParam`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) annotation on method parameters

```
@RequestMapping (...)
public String getBooks(@RequestParam(required = false, value = "sortby") String sortBy, @RequestParam(required = false, value = "year") String year) {...}
```

The `@RequestParam` annotation also has a `defaultValue` attribute to use as a value if the request parameter isn't provided. Without it, if the parameter is not provided, `null` will be passed as the argument for that parameter.

Comment: hey i have n issue. for example localhos:8080/myapp/booksearch/title/{title}/author/{author}?sortby=relevance&year=2013 is my service should i expose the service like this ?  localhos:8080/myapp/booksearch/title/{title}/author/{author}?sortby={sortby}&year={year}

Comment: @bks What do you mean by expose? Do you mean for the `@RequestMapping` or for the rest service in general?

Answer (score 1):

To get a better order you can use Swagger, it will also let you document your endpoints by the way.

You could use a Class to group your queryParams and pass it as parameter of your Controller's method, like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/books")
public String getbBoks(MyParams params) {...}
```

And for describing the params you only have to do this:

```
@ApiModel
  public class MyParams {
  @ApiParam(
    name = "sortby",
    type = "string",
    required = false
)
private String sortby;

@ApiParam(
    name = "year",
    example = "2017 , 2016",
    type = "integer",
    required = false
)
private int year;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring annotation @RequestParam is used to get the query parameter while @PathVariable is used to get the variables in path or url which are declared with curly braces like `localhost:8080/myapp/booksearch/title/{title}`.

So in your case you need @RequestParam to get the sortedBy and year values. you can simply write `public String getBooks(@RequestParam("sortby") String sortBy)`